# Django app for sending periodic emails?

Tags: django, django-email

The main functionality of it would be:

1. check a condition every day
2. if the condition is true, then send email

Now, I know how to conditionlly send email, but I don`t know how to do make it repeat ***every day***. I have some ideas but not sure about them at all (to add another process? or others?). I appreciate your suggestions and ideas...thx

Comment: You've got a good answer below. You should mark it as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom management command and use a cron job to have it run once a day.

**edit:**

I have used this before, http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/wiki/JobsScheduling. It is pretty handy if you have multiple tasks to be run on fixed schedules. Instead of having to add a line in crontab for each task you just add new files to the jobs directory.

Comment: You can find some info for setting up your cron job (assuming you're using Linux) here: http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: just curious. how is python cron? I haven't used it myself but planning use it for one of my projects. Awaiting response from experts. Thanks

Comment: I personnaly used the django-extensions jobs and I DON'T recommend it. I ended up replacing them with management command since I saw no advantage of using them.

Comment: "You must either run a job by hand, with which you can specify the exact time on which the command is ran, or put something like the following lines in your crontab file" i think i`m not interested in "by hand", but to make a crontab file is a feasible idea, or could i program a app for that like a bussiness management?